# How to open and close Ember Power Select from outside

Tags: javascript, dom, events, ember.js, ember-power-select

I'm aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46471053/how-to-open-the-dropdown-of-ember-power-select-from-outside), but is not complete. I want to open and **close** the dropdown from outside.

I can dispatch a `mousedown` event when click on my wrapper component, so `ember-power-select` trigger opens!. But then if I click again it doesn't close. More precisely, it closes and opens again rapidly.

My assumption is the component is listening `blur` event to get closed, and then the `mousedown` arrives again and open the trigger.

Has anyone managed to get this to work? or an alternative?? I'm quite lost :)

Thanks for the help!

```
wrapper-component.js 

  didInsertElement() {

    this._super(...arguments);
    this.element.addEventListener('mousedown', (event) => {
      event.stopPropagation();
      const eventedElement = this.element.querySelector('.ember-power-select-trigger');
      const mouseDownEvent = new MouseEvent('mousedown');
      eventedElement.dispatchEvent(mouseDownEvent);
    });

  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs, the only way to interact with the trigger/component is through the read-only API provided in subcomponents, blocks, and actions of the ember-power-select component.

Since you can already open the trigger you can cache the API in an `onchange` event action defined in your component (or controller of the route) where you render the ember-power-select:

Where you render the component just provide an action to `onopen`:

```
{{#ember-power-select
  options=options
  selected=selectedOption
  onchange=(action "someAction")
  onopen=(action "cacheAPI")
  as |option|}}
  {{option}}
{{/ember-power-select}}
```

In your component or controller that renders it:

```
actions: {

  cacheAPI(options) {
    if (this.powerSelectAPI) return;

    this.set('powerSelectAPI', options);

    // if you just want the actions:
    // this.set('powerSelectAPI', options.actions);
  }

}
```

Then you can open/close the trigger through the API:

```
this.get('powerSelectAPI').actions.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

RegisterAPI is solution.
From the docs:

> The function that will be called when the component is instantiated and also when any state changes inside the component, and receives a publicAPI object that the user can use to control the select from the outside using the actions in it.

```
@action
registerAPI(emberPowerSelect) {
  if (!this.emberPowerSelect) {
    this.emberPowerSelect = emberPowerSelect;
  }
}
    
@action
toggle(state) {
  if (state) {
    this.emberPowerSelect.actions.open();
  } else {
    this.emberPowerSelect.actions.close();
  }
}
```